# Interface Builder Zoom in Zoom Out

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way to zoom in/zoom out in the Interface Builder within Xcode 4?

Answer (score 34):

The current (very annoying) situation is that you can zoom in storyboards, but there is absolutely no way to zoom in a xib editing window.

Comment: It is indeed annoying. Apple pls fix this.

Answer (score 8):

XCode 5 still allows zoom in storyboards only. This is their way of telling us we should be using storyboards.

Its just never going to be possible to zoom in on a xib file.

**Edit:** Also possible: you sacrifice resolution but every mac can zoom on any part of the screen by holding Control+Scrolling Up/Down.

**Edit 2:** Accept it people, you can't zoom on xib files. But you CAN zoom your whole mac display if you prefer to view the same pixels in bigger format

Comment: heh either that or it's their way of telling us to buy a 27" Thunderbolt display -.-

Comment: Zooming is disabled by default: `System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom`.

Comment: "This is their way of telling us we should be using storyboards" Is it? Please, stick to facts in your answers. Creating reusable views in XIB is way more convenient than doing it inside Storyboard. Also "Its just never going to be possible to zoom in on a xib file" is most likely an assumption as well, but you present it as a fact.

Answer (score -1):

As of now, no. They should be adding one in xcode 4.0.3.

Comment: Just downloaded xcode 4.2... i couldnt find these controls in there... any idea where they will be?

Comment: Still no such controls in Xcode 4.6. Hate to have to use storyboards just to get a zoom feature.

Comment: Xcode 7, still waiting.